# Why can I only do a canvas of determined dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm doing a project in which I use a photo and a canvas element that draws it to know what colors are in this photo, the problem is that only lets me do this with a photo width of 300px and a height of 150px. If I put other values the canvas zooms the photo and does not let me use the whole area, I leave attached the code and some images. The problem is that, if I increase the dimensions of the photo and the dimensions of the canvas it zooms, leaving only select what is shown on the screen.

The image of 300x150
correct image

[image]

Image that doesn't work:

bad working image
[image]

```js
var xInic, yInic;
let ptop = 0;
let pleft = 0;
var estaPulsado = false;

function ratonPulsado(evt) {
  //Obtener la posición de inicio
  xInic = evt.clientX;
  yInic = evt.clientY;
  estaPulsado = true;
  //Para Internet Explorer: Contenido no seleccionable
  document.getElementById("cuadro").unselectable = true;
}

function ratonMovido(evt, left_pos) {
  if (estaPulsado) {
    //Calcular la diferencia de posición
    var xActual = evt.clientX;
    var yActual = evt.clientY;
    var xInc = xActual - xInic;
    var yInc = yActual - yInic;
    xInic = xActual;
    yInic = yActual;

    //Establecer la nueva posición
    var elemento = document.getElementById("cuadro");
    var position = getPosicion(elemento);
    elemento.style.top = (position[0] + yInc) + "px";
    elemento.style.left = (position[1] + xInc) + "px";
    ptop = position[0] + yInc
    pleft = position[1] + xInc
    return ptop, pleft;

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.estiloCuadro {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: solid red;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*Deshabilitar selección de texto*/
}

body {
  background: aqua;
}


/*img{
    width: 150px;
}*/

h1 {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}

#what {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen_1" src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-palette-generators-hero.jpg" height="150" width="300">
<span id="he"></span>
<div id="cuadro" class="estiloCuadro"></div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="color">
  <h1>El color es: </h1><br>
  <div id="what"></div>
  <p id="rf"></p>
</div>
<script src="js/main.js" async></script>
```

Comment: You have to change the size of the "canvas" (the coordinate space) via the `.height` and `.width` properties of the [`<canvas>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas). _"The displayed size of the canvas can be changed using CSS, but if you do this **the image is scaled during rendering to fit the styled size, which can make the final graphics rendering end up being distorted**. It is better to specify your canvas dimensions by setting the width and height attributes directly on the <canvas> elements, either directly in the HTML or by using JavaScript."_

Comment: Where is your code that actually draws the image?

Comment: PS are you sure you need support for IE9? Instead of `unselectable` today we simply use CSS `user-select: none;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: One point that is not aborded in the linked q/a and which might have been confusing to you is that drawImage takes the intrinsic size of the image and completely disregards the `width` and `height` of the <img> element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `width` and `height` attributes to your `<canvas>` HTML element.

You can either do this declaratively in the HTML:

```
<canvas width="1024" height="768" id="canvas></canvas>
```

Or imperatively via JavaScript:

```
const myCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
myCanvas.setAttribute('width', '1024');
myCanvas.setAttribute('height', '768');
```

Comment: And you vote to close as dupe (or at least add an explanation what the problem is, and how your "answer" fixes that)